# Scroll FlowPanel scrollbar with a Trackbar

Tags: vb.net

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel1` in my form with a bunch of buttons inside it. I wanted to change the way its scroll bar looked so I added a `TrackBar1` hoping to make it look better. I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried:

```
Panel1.AutoScroll.value = TrackBar1.Value
```

But it gives the error:

> 'value' is not a member of Boolean

What have I done wrong in this code?

Comment: [`Panel.AutoScroll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx) is a boolean indicating yes or no whether `AutoScroll` is active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it guys. I should've put `.VerticalScroll.Value` instead of `AutoScroll.Value`.

```
Panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = TrackBar1.Value
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Change it to

```
Panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = TrackBar1.Value
```

Here, `Panel1.AutoScroll` only tells you if  it's `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, `Panel1.AutoScroll` is a boolean. You need to use `HorizontalScroll.Value` or `VerticalScroll.Value` whichever matches your requirement.